# css transform scale doesn't scale parent element

Tags: html, css

I have 2 image with a link, i'm tring to scale them down to 50% of original image size, each image has a different size

if i add a back border i can see that image is correctly scaled down to half size but A tog is in original size

I'm also using bootstrap 3 in this page

```css
.header-tit-logos a {
    display: inline-block;
}
    
.header-tit-logos img {
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);      
}
```

```html
<div class="header-tit-logos">
<a href="http://www.mylink.com" target="_blank"><img src="static/images/img1.png" alt="img 1" width="60" height="117"></a>
<a href="http://www.mylink.com" target="_blank"><img src="static/images/img2.png" alt="img 2" width="145" height="54"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: `transform:scale()` is an entirely **visual** effect. It does not actually change the size of the element.

Comment: when is used it seems that it doesn't change the element space, any work around? what i would like to do is resize image based on image oginal size. img1 is 60 i would like to get it to 30px without specifying size in css but %

Comment: No...Since %age image size is based on the parent you'd have to use width/height in the CSS.

Comment: I know that is the reason i was looking for some workaround :(

Comment: @Paulie_D: If you wrote an answer saying this, I'd up-vote it. Your single sentence helped me understand what's going on better than 20 minutes of reading CSS docs and websearching. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Comment from by [@Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d) seems to be spot on and the simple answer I was looking for:

`transform:scale()` is an entirely **visual** effect. It does not actually change the size of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply style to a parent from a child.
In your case you can try to scale the parent. It'll scale both the parent and the children

```
.header-tit-logos {
-ms-transform: scale(0.5);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
transform: scale(0.5);      
 }
```

Comment: if i scale.header-tit-logos that is position absolute to its parent il get a strange position, even specifying the position is not correct

Comment: @al404IT unfortunately you cannot scale a parent from a child. Instead, try adding a position relative to the wrapper around the position absoluted element.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing width and height from img tag.

```css
.header-tit-logos a {
    background:red;
    display: inline-block;
}

.header-tit-logos img {
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5);      
}
```

```html
<div class="header-tit-logos">
    <a href="http://www.mylink.com" target="_blank"><img src="http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/medium-golden-brown-wood-texture-background-picture-id513694258?k=6&m=513694258&s=170667a&w=0&h=xETakP7VjpAtRj9e6rJRYNqw_AJLZ9ovLlC4ebR5BOQ=" alt="img 1" width="60" height="117"></a>
    <a href="http://www.mylink.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-background-in-geometric-style_1013-17.jpg" alt="img 2"></a>
</div>
```